# Easiest way to fill std::vector<double> with equidistant values

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

Assume that I have the values `double start`, `double end` and a stepsize `double step`.

What is the easiest way to fill `std::vector<double>` with values beginning at `start` and incrementing by `stepsize` as long as the current value is less than `end`?

I'm asking myself, if there is an stl function making this task a one-liner.

```
std::vector<double> fill(double start, double end, double step) {
  // Code
}

main() {
  auto ret=fill(0.2, 2.3, 0.2);
  // ret = {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, ... , 2.2}
}
```

Comment: Of course. But can I avoid the loop?

Comment: Why.............?

Comment: why and how would you want to avoid the loop? Even a one liner calling some std algorithms will perform a loop, even if it is not that obvious

Comment: First point curiosity. Second point making as much use of stl as possible.

Comment: Third point increase readability of code.

Comment: You mean decrease...

Comment: You think that would decrease readability? Can you explain why?

Comment: You can look into `std::generate()` or `std::fill()` and such but it will be more complicated than your current solution.

Comment: Wait. I'll try this out. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @FrankSimon *Assume that I have the values double start, double end and a stepsize double step* -- Note that you are risking having your program work differently due to floating point issues.  You could have a program generate less / more / different values, depending on compiler, compiler options, etc.

Comment: This is a C++ question, but it reminded me of Swift: `start.stride(to: end, by: step)` [e.g.](http://ericasadun.com/2015/05/21/swift-six-killer-features/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

again out of academic interest, and probably bending the intended design of `std::iota` to breaking point:

```
std::iota(x.begin(), x.end(), double_iota(step, min));
```

With the following definition of double_iota:

```
struct double_iota
{
    double_iota(double inc, double init_value = 0.0) : _value(init_value), _inc(inc) {}

    operator double() const { return _value; }
    double_iota& operator++() { _value += _inc; return *this; }
    double _value;
    double _inc;
};
```

Test program:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

struct double_iota
{
    double_iota(double inc, double init_value = 0.0) : _value(init_value), _inc(inc) {}

    operator double() const { return _value; }
    double_iota& operator++() { _value += _inc; return *this; }
    double _value;
    double _inc;
};

int main()
{
    double min = 1.0;
    double max = 2.3;
    double step = 0.2;

    std::vector<double> x(std::size_t(((max + step - std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()) - min) / step));
    std::iota(x.begin(), x.end(), double_iota(step, min));

    std::copy(x.begin(), x.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, ", "));
}
```

expected results:

```
1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2, 2.2,
```

update:

or we can build a custom iterator which allows us to express the sequence
truly in one line:

```
    std::vector<double> x(double_inc_iterator(min, step), double_inc_iterator(max));
```

as follows:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>


struct double_inc_iterator : std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, double>
{
    double_inc_iterator(double initial, double inc = 1.0) : _value(initial), _inc(inc) {}
    value_type operator*() const { return _value; }
    double_inc_iterator& operator++() { _value += _inc; return *this; }

    bool operator==(double_inc_iterator const& r) const { return _value >= r._value; }
    bool operator!=(double_inc_iterator const& r) const { return !(*this == r); }

    value_type _value;
    value_type _inc;
};

int main()
{
    double min = 1.0;
    double max = 2.3;
    double step = 0.2;

    std::vector<double> x(double_inc_iterator(min, step), double_inc_iterator(max));

    std::copy(x.begin(), x.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, ", "));
}
```

Now we don't even need the intermediate vector:

```
std::copy(double_inc_iterator(min, step),
          double_inc_iterator(max),
          std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, ", "));
```

Comment: Really nice solution. Especially, as double_iota represents a more reusable piece of software compared to the previous solution.

Comment: @FrankSimon since you liked it, I've added another solution which uses a custom iterator.

Comment: Brilliant solution! Could you motivate the use of `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`, please?

Comment: @anilbey I subtracted epsilon to yield a number "a tiny bit" smaller than the next element's value because I wanted to prevent the number of elements being off by one.

Comment: I can't get this code to compile with MSVC. Any idea why? Compiler message says that '=' can't convert '_Ty' to 'double'. I am referring to your original solution.

Comment: Did you include the correct header files? 
https://godbolt.org/z/YYc4veY8s

Comment: I just figured out what it was. Since I am using CLion CLang-tidy is recommending me to make the constructor and the operators explicit. Apparently that is actually causing the issue. I now realize that this approach is actually relying on the underlying code to do implicit casting, since the explicit cast is not done in the source code. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @RichardHodges `epsilon` is relative (*floating* point!): the difference between **1.0** and the next value. For large `max` it's too low, for small values it's too high...

Answer (score 2):

Just for academic purposes, you could:

```
std::vector<double> result;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(result), (size_t)((end-start)/step), [&start, step](){ auto ret=start; start+=step; return ret; });
```

Comment: That is what I'm looking for. As pointed out above it really doesn't simplify anything. Neither for a person reading the code nor for a person that needs to implement it. :-|

Comment: Exactly. Which is why it is purely academic.

Comment: This is wrong, you should:   `std::vector<double> result(1, start);` to include `start` value.

Comment: No, it's not correct yet; the first value returned by the lambda is `start+step`.

Comment: @midriot, did you actually check it? The first value returned is `ret`, which is `start`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `std::partial_sum`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

namespace detail {
    template <typename T, typename S>
    constexpr bool is_end_reachable(const T start, const T end, const S step) noexcept
    {
        return (end > start && step > 0) || start == end || (end < start && step < 0);
    }

    template <typename T, typename S>
    constexpr std::size_t num_values(const T start, const T end, const S step) noexcept
    {
        // Add one as start is always included. Add epsilon to avoid floating point errors.
        return (((end - start) + std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()) / step) + 1;
    }
} // namespace detail

template <typename T, typename S>
std::vector<T> range(const T start, const T end, const S step = 1)
{
    if (!detail::is_end_reachable(start, end, step)) {
        throw std::invalid_argument {"end not reachable from start"};
    }
    std::vector<T> result(detail::num_values(start, end, step), step);
    result.front() = start;
    std::partial_sum(std::cbegin(result), std::cend(result), std::begin(result));
    return result;
}
```

A few extra casts are needed for full type robustness but the idea is the same.

Example:

```
int main()
{
    const auto v = range(-0.1, -2.7, -0.3312);
    std::copy(std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v), std::ostream_iterator<double> {std::cout, " "});
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/640ce95b6e7af9ac)</kbd>**